# ReactJS Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-routing

I have implemented routing in my React app and I wanted to redirect non-existent routes to errorpage.

Route:

```
    <Route path="/errorpage" component={ErrorPage} />
    {/*<Route path="/:parentId/:childId" component={ErrorPage} />*/}
    <Redirect to="/errorpage" />
```

*Working:*
When I try to access **domain/notapath** --> Redirect to proper error page with css

*Not Working [Issue]*
When  I try nested routes like **domain/123/123** --> Only ErrorPage content is displayed without css.

I also tried :

```
                    <Route path="/*" component={ErrorPage} />
```

So  is there any other way to overcome this for routing to errorpage for nested paths as well which doesn't exists.?

And why this above config didn't work. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What version are you using for routing?

Comment: "react-router": "^6.8.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4"

Answer (score 0):

**You need to do this...**

`<Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />`

Comment: I got it. But the concern it. When I do domain/path --> Redirect to error page and rendered properly. 

Now when i do domain/path1/subpath1 --> Redirects find to error page , but css is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the component as below

```
<Route path="/errorpage" component={ <ErrorPage/> } />
```

Syntax for any routing as follows

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/pathname" element={ <Component/> }>
</Router>
```

Comment: I guess. I have no issue with the existing syntax for other routing. Routing and redirection happens. But only for nester routes, redirection to error page works but css is missing.